# Как собрать видео из jpeg при помощи ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть папка "D:\Frames\", в которой тысяча с лишним jpeg-изображений с именем файла (1).jpeg, (2).jpeg ... (1050).jpeg

**Как выглядят аргументы ffmpeg для преобразования содержимого этой папки в video.webm с определённым fps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы так – `ffmpeg -f image2 -i %d.jpeg -r [fps] video.webm`

Comment: "Could find no file with path 'd.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
d.jpg: No such file or directory". Вот этот %d он не воспринимает - почему?

Comment: Потому, что нет таких файлов в папке: 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg и т.д Поскольку %d.jpeg предлагает использовать именно их

Comment: @Iceman я не обратил внимания на скобки в названиях файлов

Comment: Да, уже понял. Спасибо. %d.jpg оно не найдёт, а вот (%d).jpg легко, и (%%d).jpg при вызове из bat-ника.

Answer (score 0):

Плохие названия файлов у изображений. Вот если бы было (0001).jpeg - (1050).jpeg - было бы проще. Впрочем, стоит попробовать так:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 25 -i '(*).jpeg' -s WxH video.avi
```